# I'm trying to make a program about districts and i want to store the name. I get: "No matching constructor for initialization of 'ElectionDistrict[]'"

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, clion, dynamic-arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>

const int MAX_PARTIES = 10; /* Maximum number of parties*/

class ElectionDistrict {
private:
    char* name;
    int votersCount;
    int partiesCount;
    int* partyVotes;
    std::string* partyNames;

public:
    ElectionDistrict(const char* name, int voters, int parties) /* Constructor*/
            : votersCount(voters), partiesCount(parties) {
        this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        strcpy(this->name, name);

        partyVotes = new int[partiesCount];
        partyNames = new std::string[partiesCount];
    }

    ~ElectionDistrict() {  /*Destructor*/
        delete[] name;
        delete[] partyVotes;
        delete[] partyNames;
    }

    const char* getName() const { return name; }
    int getVotersCount() const { return votersCount; }
    int getPartiesCount() const { return partiesCount; }
    const int* getPartyVotes() const { return partyVotes; }
    const std::string* getPartyNames() const { return partyNames; }

    void setPartyVotes(int partyIndex, int votes) {
        partyVotes[partyIndex] = votes;
    }

    void setPartyName(int partyIndex, const std::string& partyName) {
        partyNames[partyIndex] = partyName;
    }

};

    // Function to compare ElectionDistrict objects based on party votes
bool compareByPartyVotes(const ElectionDistrict& a, const ElectionDistrict& b) {
    return a.getPartyVotes()[0] > b.getPartyVotes()[0];
}

int main() {
    std::ofstream outFile("districts.txt");
    ElectionDistrict* districts;

    int numDistricts;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of districts: ";
    std::cin >> numDistricts;

    districts = new ElectionDistrict[numDistricts]; /* right here is the problem*/

    for (int i = 0; i < numDistricts; ++i) {
        char name[100];
        int voters, numParties;

        std::cout << "Enter the name of district " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "Enter the number of voters in " << name << ": ";
        std::cin >> voters;

        std::cout << "Enter the number of parties in " << name << ": ";
        std::cin >> numParties;

        districts[i] = ElectionDistrict(name, voters, numParties);

        for (int j = 0; j < numParties; ++j) {
            std::string partyName;
            int votes;

            std::cout << "Enter the name of party " << j + 1 << " in " << name << ": ";
            std::cin >> partyName;

            std::cout << "Enter the number of votes for " << partyName << " in " << name << ": ";
            std::cin >> votes;

            districts[i].setPartyVotes(j, votes);
            districts[i].setPartyName(j, partyName);
        }
    }
    /*writing the information about each election district and its associated parties to output file (districts.txt)*/
    for (int i = 0; i < numDistricts; ++i) { 
        outFile << districts[i].getName() << " " << districts[i].getVotersCount() << " " << districts[i].getPartiesCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < districts[i].getPartiesCount(); ++j) {
            outFile << " " << districts[i].getPartyVotes()[j] << " " << districts[i].getPartyNames()[j];
        }
        outFile << std::endl;
    }
    outFile.close();

      // Rest of the code remains the same

    delete[] districts; // Release memory

    return 0;
}
```

This code is creating ElectionDistrict and is trying imitate a program that is checking results of parties for those districts then it has to print out the winners of the districts and save after that into a separate file. The districts where there are no winners is printed out, also it has to save the information about the districts in a file.

**Using vectors on the other hand helps, but i want to make it work with dynamic arrays.**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build log.

Comment: As a hint: When you do `new ElectionDistrict[numDistricts]` you will be *default constructing* all the object in the array you create.

Comment: As for a solution, unless this exercise is about pointers, use `std::vector` for your "arrays" and `std::string` for all your strings.

Comment: You are going to have lots of issues with all those pointers. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: *Using vectors on the other hand helps,* -- It just doesn't "help", it prevents things like this from happening -- `int main() { ElectionDistrict e("abc123", 1, 1); ElectionDistrict e2 = e1; }` -- You have a double-free error.  If a two line program like that can give problems by using pointers, imagine a larger program.

Comment: `char* name;`  `std::string* partyNames;` -- Can you explain why you refused to use `std::string name;` but went ahead and used `std::string* partyNames`?  It looks like you are on purpose looking to generate problems when no problem need to exist.  The solution to this problem is to simply use `std::string` for all string data.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that `new ElectionDistrict[numDistricts]` **default constructs** the objects of/in the array but since you've provided a *parameterized constructor* for your class, the **default constructor is implicitly deleted** by the compiler as per the C++ standard rules.

To solve this you can provide a *default ctor* explicitly for your class as shown below:

```
class ElectionDistrict {
    //other code as before 

    //EXPLICITLY PROVIDE A DEFAULT CTOR
    ElectionDistrict() = default;
    
   //other code as before
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o1EjYsM3j)

---

Although unrelated to the problem, I would also recommend using `std::vector`, `std::string` inplace of arrays(so that you don't have to do manual memory management) and `char[]` respectively.

Comment: I think you need to initialize the member variables that are pointers in the default constructor.  Otherwise you have this: `int main() { ElectionDistrict e; }` causing issues.